# Cupertino Date Picker transparent background color in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create IOS style `Datepicker` and I'm trying to set the background color to transparent just like In the Photo below.
anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Example 
[image: Example]

Comment: Can you share some code? what, u have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can achieve a transparent UI easily. if you want to create UI like the first Image you posted Use Stack Widget

But, the second image you posted uses the Wheel Scroll Effect Which can be achieved using the flutter **ListWheelScrollView** Widget.

For more info on how to use check out this link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListWheelScrollView-class.html